# EF: Subclass with no table one-to-many

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm

I have the following scenario:

- A base class mapped to the database, which has several derived classes, some with their own table some not (they don't add properties).
- A derived class with no table that only has a collection of the third class (this one adds a property but has no table since it's only a relationship).
- A third class which has a foreign key to the base class table.

  ```
  public class BaseEntity
  {
      public short Id {get;set;}
      //Other Properties
  }

  [NotMapped]
  public class DerivedEntity : BaseEntity
  {
      public virtual ICollection<Message> Messages {get;set;}
  }

  public class Message
  {
      public short Id {get;set;}
      public short DerivedEntityId {get;set;}
      public virtual DerivedEntity DerivedEntity {get;set;}
      //Other Properties
  }
  ```

The schema:

```
Table BaseEntity(
    Id smallint PK,
    --Other Columns
)

Table Message(
    Id smallint PK,
    DerivedEntityId smallint FK,
    --Other Columns
)
```

And finally the mappings:

```
public BaseEntityMap(){
    ToTable(...);
    HasKey(x => x.Id);
    //Other Properties and Relationships
}

public MessaeMap(){
    ToTable(...);
    HasKey(x => x.Id);

    //This is the important part
    HasRequired(m => m.DerivedEntity)
        .WithMany(de => de.Messages)
        .HasForeignKey(m => m.DerivedEntityId);
}
```

Note that there is no map for DerivedEntity.

When EF validates the model against the DB it throws the following exception:

> The navigation property 'DerivedEntity' is not a declared property on type 'Message'. Verify that it has not been explicitly exluded from the model and that it is a valid navigation property.

I have already googled the exception but in general they were because some mappings were missing, or some typos in the FK, etc.

I can do some workaround to manually attach the messages to the correspondent DerivedEntity, but that may require two trips to the DB. Does EF have a way for handling these situations??

I am using EF 6 and SQL SERVER 2012.

Comment: Well, as for `Message`, `DerivedEntity` is not *only a relationship*. It's a very tangible reference. How could it *not* be part of the mapped model? For one, the line `HasRequired(m => m.DerivedEntity)` makes it obvious that `DerivedEntity` should be a mapped entity.

Comment: Just an addition to what Gert Arnold said. On the other hand if `DerivedEntity` is not mapped to a table, then what will you store in `DerivedEntityId` in `Message`? I presume you just need a way to group the `Message`s. If that is true then just consider making `DerivedEntityId` a normal property in `Message`, value of which can be updated just like some other property. And in that case, you don't need the reference to `DerivedEntity` object in `Message`. Otherwise, you can do as Gert Arnold said. I also personally think that a table for `DerivedEntity` is cleaner approach.

Comment: As Gert said, it had to be mapped somehow. I tried doing a MapBase<BaseEntity> class and making BaseEntityMap and DerivedEntityMap inherit from it. I was asked for the discriminator column by EF.

Sadly, after a meeting with the client's DB operator and DBA, they decided the schema (which they made) was not following their enterprise standards, so it will be reviewed and will suffer some changes. 

Meanwhile I did a workaround where DerivedEntity is still not mapped to DB and Message has a property of type BaseEntity. This implies 2 trips to the DB for retrieving a DerivedEntity